# Flat geometry popping out through smooth shading via displacement.

Tags: rendering

**As the title** suggests, here below I have a render of a ceramics object which 
used a Musgrave texture as the displacement input. However, it created some flat
shading.

Why does this phenomenon occur, and how do I revert it to keep the effects of the Musgrave displacement without the **flat shading?** (*If possible)*

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you enable smooth shading for the object? Are you using a subsurf modifier?

Comment: Yes, it's smooth shading with sub surf.